# Unable to Install postgresql on my mac os x machine via homebrew

Tags: macos, postgresql, terminal, homebrew

I was trying to install the postgres through terminal on mac os. I used homebrew to install the postgres. 
During the install I got following error

"Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/man/man3/SPI_connect.3"

I also got error regarding initdb

"initdb: file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/postgres.bki" does not exist
This might mean you have a corrupted installation or identified
the wrong directory with the invocation option -L.
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall postgresql`"

After the install I am not able to run any of postgres commands. I would really appreciate any help as I am new to postgres. Please, provide little explanation.

Thank You!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this solution is the best, but so far this is the only one.

> Note: I did this on a macOS environment

I have chowned the directory I wasn't allowed to write. (`chown -R user`/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`)`
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` (assumed that dir should be mine anyway - since it's within /**usr**/local)

I ran 
`brew link postgres` - so the links required are there

Then  `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8` worked perfectly.

Comment: For me it was an old version of postgres that hadn't been unlinked.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Running `brew postinstall postgres --debug gives:`

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Creating the directory manually and setting the right group worked:

```
cd /usr/local/var
sudo mkdir postgres
sudo chown <user> postgres
sudo chgrp admin postgres/
```